# Javascript program that shows a message after inputting age, but function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, submit

I'm trying to make a fairly easy site/program that receives a number from an input, and after submitting using a button, shows the user a message based on their input. I feel as though it should be fairly easy, but I'm having a lot of errors, such as: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. And as I tried fixing these errors (adding return false? to onsubmit on form, changing variables and syntax, etc.) I feel as if I am more stuck. I'm not sure how to make it work.

(Ignore the `lastInn` function, as it is something I did myself just to test if I could do it.)

Here is the html code:

```
<form onsubmit="return false" action="">
    <input type="number" name="inputAld" id="inputAld">

    <button type="submit" id="trykkAld" disabled="disabled" onsubmit="visAlder();">trykk på meg</button>

</form>

<p id="visHer"></p>
```

And here is the javscript file:

```
var vis, trykk; 

function lastInn() {
var but;
but = document.querySelector("#trykkAld");
but.disabled = false;
}


trykk = document.getElementById("trykkAld");
vis = document.getElementById("visHer");

document.getElementById("visHer").innerHTML ="";

function visAlder() {
  var ald;
  ald = document.getElementById("inputAld").value;

  if (ald > 10) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er et ungt barn";
  }
  else if (ald < 10 && ald > 18) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er en tenåring";
  }
  else if (ald <= 18 && ald > 30) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er en ung voksen";
  }
  else if (ald <= 30 && ald > 60) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er voksen";
  }
  else if (ald <= 60 && ald < 70){
    vis.innerHTML = "Du begynner å dra på åra"
  }
  else if (ald <= 70) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er nok gammel";
  }
  else {
    vis.innerHTML = "Hva faen er du for noe?";
}
```

}

Edit: I fixed the operators in my document.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks logically wrong.

```
  else if (ald < 10 && ald > 18) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er en tenåring";
  }
  else if (ald <= 18 && ald > 30) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er en ung voksen";
  }
  else if (ald <= 30 && ald > 60) {
    vis.innerHTML = "Du er voksen";
  }
```

Won't all these return false?

Also try wrapping your code in a document ready.

Comment: I'm currently in the process of learning Javascript for the nth time, so operators are still kind of unclear to me, but i think i fixed them now(reversed the < and >). But what will wrapping the code in document ready do? And where do i begin the wrapping?

Comment: look here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
You would want to do ```vis = document.getElementById("visHer");``` inside the ready

Comment: if the document is not rendered yet, attempting to get the element may result in null

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work. There is a missing brace at the end of the visAlder() function.
I think there is an issue with using the onsubmit in your form tag as well as in your button tag - these are probably conflicting with each other. Change your button type to type="button", change the onsubmit in your button tag to onclick and that should do it. Oh, and also remove the disabled attribute from your button tag.